# Android - Capturing video frame from GLSurfaceView and SurfacView

Tags: android, video, glsurfaceview

To play a media using Android MediaPlayer or MediaCodec, most of the time, you  use SurfaceView or GLSurfaceView (There is another way to achieve this using TextureView, but let's not talk about it here, since it's a bit different type of view)

And as far as I know, capturing the video frame from SurfaceView is not possible - you don't have access to hw overlay.
How about GLSurfaceView? Since we have access to YUV pixels (we're, right?), is it possible?

Can anyone point me where i can find a sample code to do it?
I don't think below explanation can work, because it's assuming the color format is RGBA, and in above case, I think it's YUV.
[When using GLES20.glReadPixels on android, the data returned by it is not exactly the same with the living preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606295/when-using-gles20-glreadpixels-on-android-the-data-returned-by-it-is-not-exactl)

Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: Have you seen: https://github.com/google/grafika and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that you cannot read back from a Surface.  It's the producer side of a producer-consumer pair.  GLSurfaceView is just a bunch of code wrapped around a SurfaceView that (in theory) makes working with GLES easier.

So you have to send the preview somewhere else.  One approach is to send it to a SurfaceTexture, which converts every frame sent to its Surface into a GLES texture.  The texture can then be rendered twice, once for display and once to an offscreen pbuffer that can be saved as a bitmap (just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35922245/294248)).

I'm not sure why you don't want to talk about TextureView.  It's a View that uses SurfaceTexture under the hood, and it provides a [getBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap()) call that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks fadden, The reason why I didn't want to talk about TextureView was, yes, because there is a simple way to do this using TextureView, and I was more curious about GLSurfaceView approach.